# On the behavior of the enumerate environment

Tags: enumerate, indentation

I have defined a very simple custom environment for homework problems, which is basically just `enumerate` but without the indents:

```
\newcounter{hwprob}
\newenvironment{hwprob}{\refstepcounter{hwprob} \textbf{\thehwprob.} ~ }{}
```

If I open an actual `enumerate` environment inside `hwprob`, this happens:

```
\begin{hwprob}
   \begin{enumerate}
      \item Some text.
      \item Some other text.
   \end{enumerate}
\end{hwprob}
```

[image]

I'm not sure why the first item 1. does not start on the same line as **1.** I tried removing the tilde, but to no avail. What puzzles me is that I know that when using `enumerate` inside the `proof` environment the first item will be in the same line as *Proof.*, with the correct indentation and all.

What can I do to fix this? Is this a result of how I defined `hwprob`, or is it inherent to `enumerate`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the "how" part: define `hwprob` as a list environment, and auto insert an `\item` at the beginning of `hwprob`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{hwprob}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[hwprob]{label=\textbf{\arabic*.}, first*=\item}

\begin{document}
\begin{hwprob}
   \begin{enumerate}
      \item Some text.
      \item Some other text.
   \end{enumerate}
\end{hwprob}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the "why" part, I guess it has something to do with `\trivlist` (perhaps with `\parshape`), which is the common base used by both list and theorem environments.

Comment: The LaTeX design treating many paragraph-type elements as lists causes innumerable problems, and (I believe) should be considered a misfeature.

Comment: Thanks! This works.

Answer (score 6):

The formatting you wish to achieve -- have the first item in the `enumerate` list start on the current line rather than start after a line break -- happens if the `enumerate` environment is started inside one LaTeX's `list` or `trivlist` environments.

To achieve your formatting objective, I suggest you load the enumitem package and use its `\newlist` and `\setlist` macros to create a bespoke enumerate-like list environment called `hwprob`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{hwprob}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[hwprob,1]{label=\bfseries\arabic*.,left=0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{hwprob}
\item
   \begin{enumerate}
      \item Some text.
      \item Some other text.
   \end{enumerate}
\end{hwprob}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I can't mark both answers as correct, for some reason, but you sure have my gratitude as well.